# Can I save incoming Zoom stream data directly?

Tags: display, performance, zoom-meeting, obs-studio

I'm having issues recording my Zoom meetings. My laptop is kinda crap and when it recieves the incoming zoom, having to both render it on screen AND then using OBS to screen capture seems like it's too much for the old thing.

I was wondering if it was possible to actually just save the incoming zoom stream directly. This seems like it would save a lot of graphics processing power (which my laptop does not have) and rather just is harddrive intensive (not too much of an issue). Is there a way I can directly download the incoming Zoom datastream without having to display it and then record it?

As a note, I don't need to actually watch the Zoom. I just need to save it for others to watch.

Comment: Why would you use OBS to capture it? Zoom allows recording of meetings as long as the host allows it https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/201362473-Starting-a-local-recording

Comment: If you're a paid subscriber you could use Cloud recording.

Comment: @Mokubai I've tried using the zoom local recording but it's laggy. Surprisingly, I find OBS recording Zoom to be faster